# MERN Up/Down Vote Not Updating Without Browser Refresh

Tags: reactjs, express, mern

I am studying the MERN stack and trying to build a forum app whereby comments can be up/downvoted. Via React, a parent component connected to a MongoDB through Express passes state(props) to a child component which then maps the props and also contains the logic for the up/down voting. The problem is after clicking to vote and the server responds to the fetch the state of the counter( {x.score} in the map method) is not updated without refreshing the browser.

Typically, updating state is pretty straightforward. However, my code has grown a bit unwieldy for my basic skills. My questions are: 1. how to alter this code so that the state of the counter updates without a manual browser refresh. 2. whether the overall architecture of this code is correct, i.e. should passing props to a child component be avoided in this case? should hooks and useEffect be used instead? Or, even should I alter the click logic in the return?

I had a hard time finding any comprehensive internet sources on MERN voting. Also, I would prefer to set up a example via stackblits or other, however, this code is dependent upon a mongoDB source and express server.

child component:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      comments: this.props.comments,
    }
  }
  upvote = (x) => {
    const user = accountService.userValue;
    if (user) {
      fetch(`http://localhost:4000/posts/comment/${x}/upvote`, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
           'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({user :user.id})
      })
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.success) {
            this.updateComment(res.comment);
          } else {
            console.log('oops: ' + res.message);
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    } else {
      alert('Please sign up to vote!');
    }
  };
  updateComment = (updatedComment) => {
    let comments = [...this.props.comments];
    comments.forEach((comment, index) => {
      if (comment._id === updatedComment._id) {
        comments[index] = updatedComment;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ comments });
  };
    ...
  render(){
   return(
    ...
        {this.props.comments.map((x,y)=>(
          <div key={y} className="row p-2 border-tlr-3l1">
            <div className="col-1 d-flex align-items-center">
              <div className="rank">{x.score}</div>
              <div className="votes"></div>
              <i className={`fas fa-thumbs-up ${user && x.upvotedby.includes(user.id) ? 'upvoted' : ''}`} onClick={this.upvote.bind(this, x._id)}></i>
              <i className={`fas fa-thumbs-down ${user && x.downvotedby.includes(user.id) ? 'downvoted' : ''}`} onClick={this.downvote.bind(this, x._id)}></i>
            </div>
            <div className="col-11">
              <p  className="lead mb-0"> {x.comment_body}</p>
              <small className="color-3">posted by <span className="color-1l">{x.userName}</span></small>
              <small className="color-3"> on {moment(x.createdAt).format('MM/DD/YYYY')}</small>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
```

Comment: At any rate: I’ve been trying to help you understand why edits like halfer made are done here, and that *this is normal and not something you can opt out of*. The right place to debate that policy would be on [meta], but until the community decides to abandon that policy I’m going to have to ask you to not post those comments again or to roll back such edits.

Comment: If you don’t like the policy, the other option is to not post your questions here.

Comment: This discussion is over. Either take it to [meta], or use the contact us link in the footer, if you wish to pursue this further.

Answer (score 1):

You're updating the state comments, but when you go to render you're using `this.props.comments`.  Try using the comments in state to render.

You'll want to update two spots

1. In your Render

```
...
{this.state.comments.map((x,y)=>(
          <div key={y} className="row p-2 border-tlr-3l1">
...
```

2. In your update

```
...
  updateComment = (updatedComment) => {
    let comments = [...this.state.comments];
...
```

If you don't change your update, the next update will clear the previous.